# What is best approach in MAUI (iOS/Android) to recognize that Entry is part of Login/Password combination and trigger Password Auto-Fill?

Tags: maui

I have a MAUI app (targeting iOS and Android) where I originally labeled the input fields as "Login" and "Password". This caused my installed password manager (LastPass) to pop up when I clicked in the "Login" field. However, I later decided to change the label of the "Login" field to "Account Number" to better match the naming conventions in my app's UI. Now, the password manager no longer automatically populates the "Account Number" field when I click in it (it still works when I click in the "Password" field).

```
            <Entry
               Placeholder="Account number" 
               Text="{Binding AccountNumber}" 
               AutomationId="AccountNumber"
               Keyboard="Numeric" />
```

What is the best approach for getting MAUI possibly in conjunction with the underlying OS to recognize that this Entry is part of a Login/Password combination?

There is a IsPassword property but it causes the Entry to get masked which I don't want of course.

Comment: Have you read the LastPass docs to see what triggers activate it?

Comment: Maybe change AutomationId to "Login"?